# Unity: Custom Procedural Skybox disappears at build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, procedural, skybox

Following this process
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UIbkfVWYRWQ

I made a custom skybox procedural material for my app and applied it in the lighting panel.

It works fine but when I make a build for Android, during the building process, the custom skybox is replaced with the "Default-Skybox"

Once the build is done, the custom skybox comes back

I found that
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1211015/procedural-skybox-no-longer-working-on-android-bui.html

But I can't find how to "Delete the shader from the standard asset package"

Comment: well look to see what shader it uses, search for it in the standard assets and delete it

Comment: @BugFinder could you give me a bit more info so that I know how to find out "what shader it uses" and how to "Delete the shader from the standard asset package" ?

Comment: How on earth would we know what shaders are used, Im not watching the youtube video to find out.

Comment: the only shader I know of is the one I assigned to the new material I made for my custom Skybox. it is called "Skybox/Procedural"